# PHPExcel CyclicReferenceStack not found

Tags: phpexcel

I just upgraded PHPExcel to the latest one. In my code I call 
`$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file['tmp_name']);` 
for an uploaded xlsx file. I get this error: **Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_CalcEngine_CyclicReferenceStack' not found in /home/rrd/public_html/laksmi/app/Vendor/PHPExcel/Calculation.php on line 1733**

I tried to delete all formulas, and just have only one sheet, and I get the same error. How should I solve this?

Comment: You certainly shouldn't get that error when loading a file, because nothing in the load file code should be referencing the calculation engine.... is your code ding anything else with the file?

Comment: Mark: No, the error comes exactly at this line. Before this I just import the PHPExcel library. This is the stack: 7 0.0897 1212704 ImportsController->excelImport( ) ../ImportsController.php:33
8 0.0905 1259808 PHPExcel_IOFactory::load( ) ../ImportsController.php:595
9 0.0920 1299072 PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->load( ) ../IOFactory.php:192
10 0.0920 1299340 PHPExcel->__construct( ) ../Excel2007.php:351
11 0.0928 1463272 PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance( ) ../PHPExcel.php:360
12 0.0932 1467016 PHPExcel_Calculation->__construct( ) ../Calculation.php:1767

Comment: Can you tell me what version of PHPExcel..... I know the code reasonably well, and know that it certainly shouldn't be calling the Calculation engine at any point during a read; but it looks like a broken autoloader, or you're using a non-SPL-registered autoloader alongside PHPExcel, or you don't have all the PHPExcel class files

Comment: It is 1.8.0. I downloaded today from the official website and I overwrote my former PHPExcel library. When it did not worked I downloaded and overwrote again.

Comment: Trying to replicate.... do you have any other autoloaders?

Comment: I deleted the library folder and copy there again. Now it is working. Maybe I had some former file what was unnecessary now, or file permission error... Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

had the same error! just make chmod of the whole folder 777 and its working again
because maybe you overwrote the old folders which had set the right permission but calcengine folder is new!

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same error after updating from an older version of PHPExcel.

1. Renamed the old directory (as a convenient backup).
2. Added the latest source as a new directory, with the original folder name.
3. Tested locally and saw no problems.
4. Committed the changes to git (git commit -A for tracked and untracked files).
5. Pushed the git repo to my production environment.
6. "Class 'PHPExcel_CalcEngine_CyclicReferenceStack' not found" message in production

After some quick debugging, I found that the git commit after swapping out files in steps #1 and #2 didn't capture PHPExcel's newer CalcEngine directory. Not sure why this occurred, but I ran another git commit -A and it appeared to synchronize correctly.